# Windows Authentication localhost vs fully qualified name

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, windows-authentication

Can someone please explain to me why I get two different results when running the same software?  I've got a .NET Core application running with IIS.

When I access it as `http://localhost/foo` it all works as expected.  I authenticate properly.

When I access it as `http://machine.domain.com/foo` I get a credentials dialog appear, asking me to enter a username/password and no matter what I type in I can't get it to authenticate.

It's the same piece of software running on the same box.  The only difference is the URL I'm using to access it.  My guess is that it must be something on the network causing this problem.

Btw, this machine is just being accessed across a corporate lan.  Not the internet.